# PayPal button changing values

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

In adding a PayPal button to my website, a question occurred to me: is it not possible to change the product value from the console since it is client-side JavaScript? Here is the code:

```
paypal.Buttons({

// sets up the transaction when a payment button is clicked

createOrder: (data, actions) => (

return actions.order.create((

purchase_units: [

amount:{

value: '77.44'

}
```

Regardless of the wrong or missing parentheses, to talk about the idea, is it possible to change the value from the console and affect the resulting transaction?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible.

`actions.order.create` and `actions.order.capture` are deprecated. These functions should not be used for any new integrations.

Instead, see the current [standard checkout integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/), which uses backend API calls for order creation and capture. The code example there is in node.js, but you can of course use any language/environment for the backend environment of the implementation, including PHP.

Comment: this mean that the client can hack the pay by changing the value easily?

Comment: Anything on the client side can potentially be changed.